# Phone.IS_PRIMARY not giving primary number for contact: Android

Tags: android, default, contacts, phone-number

I am trying to fetch the primary number of a contact in Android but not getting the desired result.

Using the following code

```
 cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null);

                phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                        String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                        Log.d(TAG,"Number:::"+ phoneNumber);
                        int primary = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.IS_PRIMARY);
                        Log.d(TAG, "primary value:::"+ primary);
                        allNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                }
```

I have a contact with 2 numbers. One of them is set to primary by holding the number for long and choosing "set as default". When I run this code on the said contact, the PHONE.IS_PRIMARY returns 45 for both the numbers.

I wish to know which of the number has been set to default for a contact.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Phone.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY` as [per the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#IS_SUPER_PRIMARY)

> Whether this is the primary entry of its kind for the aggregate contact it belongs to. Any data record that is "super primary" must also be "primary". For example, the super-primary entry may be interpreted as the default contact value of its kind (for example, the default phone number to use for the contact).